# Filter causing Circular Reference Error - Not obvious why?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have 3 sheets. SheetA and SheetB contain data and a third sheet where I want to merge the contents of the SheetA and SheetB in it.

I type this formula in the result sheet (the 3rd sheet):

```
={filter(SheetA!A1:A, arrayformula(ISBLANK(A:A)=false)),
filter(SheetB!A1:A, arrayformula(ISBLANK(A:A)=false))}
```

However, I get circular reference error! Not sure what caused it? Each filter in the above expression works correctly.

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/103ef2eFOrjUKZCxtZgArExn5wkZqab5v2mwjfr1a8bk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome. Your formula should work. Please share a test sheet so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: @marikamitsos, thanks for willing to help. I modified the post with the sheet link.

Comment: Do not share the published version. Just the sheet.

Comment: The sheet has just some test data, Column A has some data in sheetA and SheetB - That is all. - I have this address for the sheet itself: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/103ef2eFOrjUKZCxtZgArExn5wkZqab5v2mwjfr1a8bk/edit#gid=1407099331 but I think you won't be able to access it.

Comment: You have to give it editing or viewing access.

Comment: Sorry for troubling you. I am not sure how to allow edits. As I said it is just sample data placed in column A of the first 2 sheets, then the formula is entered in the 3rd sheet at the top cell - You can reproduce it in a minute. Thanks.

Comment: Please read how to and [share the test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311).

Comment: I appreciate your help. I did update the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that in your sheet `Result` in cell `A1` (that is in column `A`) you have a formula like

```
={filter(SheetA!A1:A, arrayformula(ISBLANK(A:A)=false)),
filter(SheetB!A1:A, arrayformula(ISBLANK(A:A)=false))}
```

Meaning, you get `circular reference error` because you refer to column `A` by using `ISBLANK(A:A)` in your formula.

**Your formula will work if you place your formula in any other column in sheet `Result` BUT `A`.**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. When I moved the formula in the result sheet to another column I got another error but the circular reference issue is gone. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to accept. Please update your sheet with the new error so we can probably solve that one as well.

Comment: I appreciate your willing to help. Never mind, I will try on my own. Thanks again.